# Flash Fallback Not Working with IE7 on Windows XP SP2

Tags: mediaelement.js

I've been testing a site using MediaElement.JS and have been very impressed thus far. I have tested the Flash fallback support on FF and Safari on Mac. I've also tested it on Windows 7 with IE9 and Google Chrome. Everything works and if the codec cannot load it uses the mp4 version of the video I have with the Flash player.

However, upon testing it in IE7, the Flash player does not load. I do not even see any controls for the video and with right-clicking on the element I do not get the standard Flash settings menu. It does however have a black box where the element should appear (and it's not my styling).

Here is my video element block with Flash fallback support:

```
<video id="video-tag" width="640" height="360" poster="war-torn.png" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <!-- MP4 for Safari, IE9, iPhone, iPad, Android, and Windows Phone 7 -->
    <source id="source-mp4" type="video/mp4" src="war-torn.mp4" />
    <!-- WebM/VP8 for Firefox4, Opera, and Chrome -->
    <!-- Flash fallback for non-HTML5 browsers without JavaScript -->
    <object width="320" height="240" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster=war-torn.png&file=war-torn.mp4" />
        <!-- Image as a last resort -->
        <img src="war-torn.png" width="320" height="240" title="No video playback capabilities" />
    </object>
</video>
```

I am implementing MediaElement.JS further down in my page like so:

```
<script src="../build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#video-tag").mediaelementplayer({
  features: ['playpause','progress','current','volume']
});
</script>
```

I am not sure what is going on since if I remove the tag for WebM and FF uses the Flash fallback it works perfectly. If anyone has any insight, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

I receive this error message as well:

> '0.url' is null or not an object
>
> mediaelement-and-player.min.js
>
> Code: 0
>
> URI: *url to js file*
>
> Line: 41
>
> Char: 4

It does not work in IE7 compatibility mode either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing two things. First, I moved the `mediaelement-and-player.min.js` script tag up to the head and, next, I moved the `.mediaelementplayer()` call after the html for the video tag.

This appears to have resolved the problem. Weird.