# Media Element IE7 fast forward issue

Tags: internet-explorer-7, mediaelement.js

Using a media element works great, except when I run it in ie7 the strangest thing happens. It begins to play really fast. It starts jumping about 30 seconds at a time.

Also I found this only happens on videos that are large file size like 50 mb or more.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: always try asking google first... and post your code as well

Answer (score 0):

Just done simple google search found bunch of solutions to your problem.

[Mediaelement.js malfunction in IE, no flashback works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190831/mediaelement-js-malfunction-in-ie-no-flashback-works)
[Flash Fallback Not Working with IE7 on Windows XP SP2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126932/flash-fallback-not-working-with-ie7-on-windows-xp-sp2)
[Internet explorer 6,7,8 with flash player 12 failing #1078](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1078)

good luck!